# operator precendence grammar

Tags: terminology, formal-grammars, parsers

According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397767/computing-leading-and-trailing-sets-for-context-free-grammar while constructing operator precendence parser we have to create tabel with operator. Actually i dont understand the rules which tells how to build such table. 
For example take last production `term   -> '(' expr ')'` do we use rule `terminal nonterminal` because of `( expr` or  do we use rule `nonterminal terminal` because of `expr )` or do we use rule `terminal nonterminal terminal` shoudl we divide production or treat as whole? Then is there any other rule applicable in example from link then `terminal nonterminal terminal` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that answer is clear (although of course I would do, because I wrote it).

What it says is:

> if you find

$$nonterminal\; TERMINAL$$

> in any production, then you add the precedence relations $TRAIL \gtrdot TERMINAL$ for every $TRAIL$ in $Trailing(nonterminal)$. Similarly, every occurrence of

$$TERMINAL\; nonterminal$$

> generates the relationships $TERMINAL \lessdot LEAD$ for every $LEAD$ in $Leading(nonterminal)$.

So in $'(' expr ')'$, you have both an instance of $TERMINAL\; nonterminal$ and an instance of $nonterminal\; TERMINAL$, and you need to deal with both of them independently.

Comment: Do we have `$` operator in such gramma or we ignore it?

Comment: Do you mean the convention of augmenting grammars with an end-of-input symbol? If so, that is usually done in order to finish the parse. Since the only use of `$` in the grammar will be in the augmented production `S' -> S $`, we can conclude that every terminal `T` which has a relation with `$` has the relation `T ⋗ $`. In practice, it's easy to just add that relation to every terminal.